# Use of 'auto' as vehicle name

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, etymology, latin

The word bus, is derived from the word *Omnibus* in Latin since it means *for everyone*. 
Over the years this probably got shortened down to bus.

Similarly, the word car is derived from the word *Carrum* which literally means *wagon* in Latin.

However, why is *auto* used to describe this vehicle used in India when it actually means *self* in Latin?
[image]

Comment: Because there are no horses.

Comment: "Automobile" became the preferred term (after much angst) for motor vehicles in the US.  I gather that this term was imported via French.  "Auto" is an obvious shortening.

Comment: The auto rickshaw pictured is also called a tuk-tuk. Rickshaws were originally powered (and still are) by humans.

Comment: If you vehicle was made in Germany, that its name is *Otto* not *auto*.

Answer (score 1):

*Auto* is short for *automobile*, meaning 'moving itself' (i.e. not needing horses). Although we usually say *(motor) car* in Britain, the two original motorists' organisations are the Automobile Association (AA) and the Royal Automobile Club (RAC).